# Remove missing values with user defined function

Tags: r, user-defined-functions

I have a dataset as data with missing values.

```
a <- sample(1:100,15)
b <- sample(1:20,15)
data <- data.frame(a,b)
data[c(3,6,8,12),2] <- NA
data
```

Now I want to delete the rows with missing values by one variable at a time. (Don't want to use na.omit() ). I have written the following function, but it's not working.

```
rmv_missing <- function(y,z){
z <- z[is.na(z$y) == TRUE,]
return(z)
}
rmv_missing("b",data)
```

Also tried this one...

```
library(dplyr)
na_values <- function(x,y,z){
z <- (filter(z,!is.na(y)))
return(z)
}
rmv_missing("b",data)
```

None of these functions are working. Could someone help me to understand where did I make the mistake and rectify the code. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

First thing, you don't really need the "== T" since the "is.na" function spits out already a logical vector. The other problem is that accessing a data.frame as "data$b" will not work within a function. So instead, do the following *et voilà*:

```
rmv_missing <- function(y,z)
{
  print(z$y) # Does not work
  print(z[, y]) # Works
  
  z[is.na(z[, y]),]
}

rmv_missing("b",data)
# NULL
# [1]  9 16 NA  5 13 NA  8 NA 11 17 20 NA 10 12  1
#     a  b
# 3  33 NA
# 6  59 NA
# 8  81 NA
# 12 26 NA
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! Your suggestion helped me to understand and rectify my mistake.